# Root element without children. JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How can I parse something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<response>1</response>
```

?

Comment: Use @XmlValue - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496052/what-is-the-jaxb-equivalent-of-a-text-node-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {

    @XmlValue
    private int value:

}
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
Integer response = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, Integer.class).getValue();
```